# How to find audio track presence

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios6

How can I find whether a audio track is present in a video? I am using AVUrlAsset class to load assets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ([[asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] count] > 0)
{
AVAssetTrack *sourceAudioTrack = [[asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0];
[trackB insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, [asset duration]) ofTrack:sourceAudioTrack atTime:kCMTimeZero error:&error];
}
```